# Card.Io iOS scan name

Tags: ios, objective-c, card.io

I am using the CardIOView and CardIOViewDelegate classes and there is no BOOL that I can set to YES for scanning collectCardholderName. I can see it is available in the CardIOPaymentViewController however I am not using those view controller classes.

I am declaring CardIOView like below.

```
@property(nonatomic, strong, readwrite) IBOutlet CardIOView *cardIOViewer;
```

and accessing and setting its properties like below in viewDidLoad.

```
self.cardIOViewer.hideCardIOLogo = YES;
self.cardIOViewer.scanExpiry = YES;
```

I want to be able to scan the users name also ie below as the documentation says the default is false however that property isn't available?

```
self.cardIOViewer.collectCardholderName = YES
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't appear that name scanning is supported by CardIO at the moment. It allows the name to be entered manually, but only the card number (and optionally expiration) can be scanned.